# Cocos2d-x: deprecated class Object

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to learn from a sample source code (Since the framework is utterly undocumented) that was written for cocos2d-x 3.0alpha, the code is using the deprecated class "Object", I'm trying to port the code to version 3.0 but I'm not sure which class be used instead of Object.

Do you have any idea?

https://github.com/OiteBoys/Earlybird/blob/master/Earlybird/Classes/Number.h

Edit: pretty sure the class I need is Ref

---

Current issue I'm trying to solve is finding the equivalent of EGLView::getInstance()

Edit II: GLView::create("view"); seems to be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need `Ref`. Here are the release notes for Version 3.0. It describes this here. This changes was done since C++ doesn't have and doesn't need a base object. `Object` was created for that reason originally but now deprecated.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/docs/RELEASE_NOTES.md

For `EGLView` create a quick sample "Hello World" project using the `cocos` command-line tool and have a look at `AppController.mm`, `RootViewController.mm` and `AppDelegate.cpp`. These have changed a good deal for version 3.0+.

Edit: based upon your edit look at: `bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()`

```
// initialize director
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My Game");
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a source of tutorials on cocos2d-x? I can't find anything in English about it.

Comment: Have a look at the Wiki: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki It is growing daily. Also, there is a Forum for asking questions, etc.